# How do you use sed from Perl?

Tags: perl, sed

I know how to use `sed` with `grep`, but within Perl the below fails. How can one get `sed` to work within a Perl program?

```
chomp (my @lineNumbers=`grep -n "textToFind" $fileToProcess | sed -n 's/^\([0-9]*\)[:].*/\1/p'`)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm surprised that nobody mentioned the [s2p](http://perldoc.perl.org/s2p.html) utility, which translates sed "scripts" (you know, most of the time oneliners) to valid perl. (And there's an a2p utility for awk too...)

Answer (score 28):

Suggestion: Use Perl regular expressions and replacements instead of grep or sed.

It's approximentally the same syntax, but more powerful.  Also in the end it will be more efficient than invoking the extra sed process.

Comment: Agreed, better not to take unnecessary detours outside the language's available API's.

Comment: Personal taste, perhaps, but some example code would be spiffy.

Comment: @Chris: You're right, so I upvoted Paul Tomblin who already did so.

Answer (score 15):

Anything you need to do with grep or sed can be done natively in perl more easily.  For instance (this is roughly right, but probably wrong):

```
my @linenumbers;
open FH "<$fileToProcess";
while (<FH>)
{
   next if (!m/textToFind/);
   chomp;
   s/^\([0-9]*\)[:].*/\1/;
   push @lineNumbers, $_;
}
```

Comment: A matter of taste, but: I would use 'next unless' rather than !m///

Comment: "unless" just seems too much like INTERCAL's "COME FROM" for me.

Comment: I've seen it recommended that you use $1 instead of \1 in Perl.  It's supposed to have better performance or something like that.

Comment: Perl is so lingually diverse that things like 'if not or unless' and '\1 or $1' can be debated until the cows come home. Its all personal preference. Larry has some comments and guidelines on the matter but most ppl just write perl how they would say it. Which really helps your flow when coding in perl :)

Comment: @ekerner - I swear more when I'm writing perl than when I'm talking.

Answer (score 4):

Supposedly Larry Wall wrote Perl because he found something that was impossible to do with sed and awk. The other answers have this right, use Perl regular expressions instead. Your code will have fewer external dependencies, be understandable to more people (Perl's user base is much bigger than sed user base), and your code will be cross-platform with no extra work.

Edit: Paul Tomblin relates an excellent story in his comment on my answer. I'm putting it here to increase it's prominence.

"Henry Spencer, who did some amazing things with Awk, claimed that after demoing some awk stuff to Larry Wall, Larry said he wouldn't have bothered with Perl if he'd known." – Paul Tomblin

Comment: Look for 's2p', the sed to Perl converter; comes with Perl still.

Comment: Henry Spencer, who did some amazing things with Awk, claimed that after demoing some awk stuff to Larry Wall, Larry said he wouldn't have bothered with Perl if he'd known.

Comment: I am extremely glad that Larry *hadn't* known.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Use power Luke:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\na"|perl -lne'/a/&&print$.'
1
3
```

Thus when you want same think as this slow and overcomplicated `grep` and `sed` combination you can do it far simpler and faster in perl itself:

```
my @linenumbers;
open my $fh, '<', $fileToProcess or die "Can't open $fileToProcess: $!";
while (<$fh>)
{
   /textToFind/ and push @lineNumbers, $.;
}
close $fh;
```

Or with same memory culprits as the original solution

```
my @linenumbers = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $fileToProcess or die "Can't open $fileToProcess: $!";
    my $i;
    map { ( ++$i ) x /textToFind/ } <$fh>
};
```

Comment: Did you skip the spaces in "perl -lne'/a/&&print$.'" on purpose?  I was tempted to edit it to add spaces but didn't know if there was any reason for them.

Comment: No, there is not any purpose but just to be shorter as usual when code golfing. In perl 5.10 you can be even more brief perl -nE'/a/&&say$.' It should work exactly same as perl -ne '/a/ and print "$.\n"' or perl -ne 'if ($_ =~ m/a/) { print $., "\n" }' etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
perl -pe 's/search/replace/g'
```

in place of

```
sed 's/search/replace/'
```

.. However ..

Those are meant for command line or shell scripts.
Since youre already in a perl script,
 the correct answer was given by "Paul Tomblin" above.

Have fun,
eKerner.com

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. In my case (a bash script), I needed something like `sed`, but with proper PCRE support, and nothing supports PCRE better than Perl itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a large `sed` expression, you could use `s2p`, to convert it into a `perl` program.

If you run  <`s2p 's/^\([0-9]*\)[:].*/\1/p'`>, this is what you would get:

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl -w
eval 'exec /opt/perl/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
  if 0;
$0 =~ s/^.*?(\w+)[\.\w+]*$/$1/;

use strict;
use Symbol;
use vars qw{ $isEOF $Hold %wFiles @Q $CondReg
         $doAutoPrint $doOpenWrite $doPrint };
$doAutoPrint = 1;
$doOpenWrite = 1;
# prototypes
sub openARGV();
sub getsARGV(;\$);
sub eofARGV();
sub printQ();

# Run: the sed loop reading input and applying the script
#
sub Run(){
    my( $h, $icnt, $s, $n );
    # hack (not unbreakable :-/) to avoid // matching an empty string
    my $z = "\000"; $z =~ /$z/;
    # Initialize.
    openARGV();
    $Hold    = '';
    $CondReg = 0;
    $doPrint = $doAutoPrint;
CYCLE:
    while( getsARGV() ){
    chomp();
    $CondReg = 0;   # cleared on t
BOS:;
# s/^\([0-9]*\)[:].*/\1/p
{ $s = s /^(\d*)[:].*/${1}/s;
  $CondReg ||= $s;
  print $_, "\n" if $s;
}
EOS:    if( $doPrint ){
            print $_, "\n";
        } else {
        $doPrint = $doAutoPrint;
    }
        printQ() if @Q;
    }

    exit( 0 );
}
Run();

# openARGV: open 1st input file
#
sub openARGV(){
    unshift( @ARGV, '-' ) unless @ARGV;
    my $file = shift( @ARGV );
    open( ARG, "<$file" )
    || die( "$0: can't open $file for reading ($!)\n" );
    $isEOF = 0;
}

# getsARGV: Read another input line into argument (default: $_).
#           Move on to next input file, and reset EOF flag $isEOF.
sub getsARGV(;\$){
    my $argref = @_ ? shift() : \$_; 
    while( $isEOF || ! defined( $$argref = <ARG> ) ){
    close( ARG );
    return 0 unless @ARGV;
    my $file = shift( @ARGV );
    open( ARG, "<$file" )
    || die( "$0: can't open $file for reading ($!)\n" );
    $isEOF = 0;
    }
    1;
}

# eofARGV: end-of-file test
#
sub eofARGV(){
    return @ARGV == 0 && ( $isEOF = eof( ARG ) );
}

# makeHandle: Generates another file handle for some file (given by its path)
#             to be written due to a w command or an s command's w flag.
sub makeHandle($){
    my( $path ) = @_;
    my $handle;
    if( ! exists( $wFiles{$path} ) || $wFiles{$path} eq '' ){
        $handle = $wFiles{$path} = gensym();
    if( $doOpenWrite ){
        if( ! open( $handle, ">$path" ) ){
        die( "$0: can't open $path for writing: ($!)\n" );
        }
    }
    } else {
        $handle = $wFiles{$path};
    }
    return $handle;
}

# printQ: Print queued output which is either a string or a reference
#         to a pathname.
sub printQ(){
    for my $q ( @Q ){
    if( ref( $q ) ){
            # flush open w files so that reading this file gets it all
        if( exists( $wFiles{$$q} ) && $wFiles{$$q} ne '' ){
        open( $wFiles{$$q}, ">>$$q" );
        }
            # copy file to stdout: slow, but safe
        if( open( RF, "<$$q" ) ){
        while( defined( my $line = <RF> ) ){
            print $line;
        }
        close( RF );
        }
    } else {
        print $q;
    }
    }
    undef( @Q );
}
```

Not exactly worth doing on small expressions.

Comment: Looks like s2p is a good place for someone who wants to do some optimization and improvement of existing open source software.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can use Perl as a replacement for Sed:

Instead of:

```
sed "s/xxx/yyy/g" files_to_process
```

Use:

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/xxx/yyy/g" files_to_process
```

This will modify the files *in-place* and make a backup (`.bak`) of each modified file.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: OK, I fixed it now.

```
use File::Grep qw/fmap/;

my @lineNumbers = fmap { /$pattern/ ? $_[1] : () } $fileToProcess;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use Perl than to use grep and sed; see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/611945/3614563).

Your code failed because Perl messed with the backslashes in your sed code.  To prevent this, write your sed code in `'a single-quoted Perl string'`, then use `\Q$sedCode\E` to interpolate the code into the shell command.  (About `\Q...E`, see [perldoc -f quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).  Its usual purpose is to quote characters for regular expressions, but [it also works with shell commands](http://blog.thewebsitepeople.org/2014/03/shell-escaping-in-perl/).)

```
my $fileToProcess = "example.txt";
my $sedCode = 's/^\([0-9]*\)[:].*/\1/p';
chomp(my @linenumbers =
      `grep -n "textToFind" \Q$fileToProcess\E | sed -n \Q$sedCode\E`);
printf "%s\n", join(', ', @linenumbers);
```

Given `example.txt` with

```
this has textToFind
this doesn't
textToFind again
textNotToFind
```

the output is `1, 3`.