# How to use sed in Perl program?

Tags: perl

How can one get to work the below command within a *Perl* program?

```
cat file| sed -n '/Later/p' | 
sed -n '/A character range is written as two characters separated by{}/!p' | 
sed -n '/ range is not specified{}/!p'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use sed from Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/611366/how-do-you-use-sed-from-perl)

Comment: Are you asking how to launch `sed` from Perl, or are you asking how to implement that code in Perl? If it's the former, `system`. If it's the latter, what does that do, and what's giving you a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Preferably not at all. Perl gives you so much more than plain sed, you would not pay the overhead of shelling out just to use sed if you can do the same thing in Perl itself:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $filehandle, '<', 'file' or die "could not open file: $!\n";

while (<$filehandle>) {
    if ( /pattern one/ and not /pattern two/ and not /pattern three/ ) { print }
}
```