# How do you use sed in Perl (part 2)?

Tags: perl, sed

This is a similar question to this thread [How do you use sed from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/611366/how-do-you-use-sed-from-perl)

My question is:  I have a pipeline of sed in a csh statement such as this:

```
set lineNumbers= `grep "textToFind" $fileToProcess | s/.*textToFind //' | sed 's/;.*//'`
```

I would like to solve this issue without using s2p module such as this:

```
my @linenumbers;
open FH "<$fileToProcess";
while (<FH>)
{
   next if (!m/textToFind/);
   chomp;
   s/.*textToFind //, s/;.*//;
   push @lineNumbers, $_;
}
```

But not sure how to include the sed pipeline in this way without using the module. I separated the second pipeline with a comma. Not sure if that is a right syntax. Any help to include both the pipeline of sed  after the chomp would be appreciable.

Thank you!

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Find the line numbers of the file where the textToFind is found?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  Do you want to know how to [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) the result of your 1st example in spite of the many virtues of the 2nd approach?

Comment: Your question is "How do I use this approach", but you didn't specify the approach to which you are referring. (The approach taken by the accepted answer uses `s2p`, which you specifically excluded.)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how perl works. A pattern by default applies to `$_`. `$_` is (by default) the current line. So all you need do is `s/onething/anotherthing/; s/somethingelse/whatever/; print $_;`

Comment: I was assuming this approach                                                               """my @linenumbers;
open FH "<$fileToProcess";
while (<FH>)
{
   next if (!m/textToFind/);
   chomp;
   s/.*textToFind //, s/;.*//;
   push @lineNumbers, $_;
}    """" 
didnt use the s2p. May be I have misunderstood that this approach did'nt use s2p.

Answer (score 2):

What I think you are asking for is something like:

```
my @linenumbers;
open my $INPUT_FH, '<', $fileToProcess;
while (<$INPUT_FH>)
{
   next if (!m/textToFind/);
   push @lineNumbers, $.;
}
```

[$.](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24.) is the perl variable for the line of the current file handle.

Comment: Thanx for the style catch. Though it's my style to put my ($var) in parans to set it off....

Comment: Don't. It's a bad habit. Brackets (can) alter context. That can have some subtle and nasty side effects.